# Classify a surface

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering if it is possible to classify a surface by finding the fundamental group.

For a surface X, if $\pi_1(X)=G$, how to classify $X$?

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the surfaces to possibly be non-compact, then there are non-homeomorphic surfaces with the same fundamental group. For example $\pi_1(\Bbb{R}^2)$ and $\pi_1(S^2)$ are both trivial.

If we insist that our surfaces are compact without boundary, then the fundamental group is a complete invariant of the surface. The fundamental group of the oriented surface $\Sigma_g$ of genus $g$ is 
$$\pi_1(\Sigma_g) = \langle a_1, \dots, a_g, b_1,\dots, b_g| [a_1,b_1]\cdots[a_g,b_g]=1\rangle.$$
The fundamental group of the non-orientable surface $F_g=\underbrace{\Bbb{RP}^2 \#\cdots\#\Bbb{RP}^2}_{g}$ is
$$\pi_1(F_g) = \langle c_1,\dots, c_g| c_1^2 c_2^2\cdots c_g^2 = 1\rangle.$$
These groups are all distinct. One can see this by taking their [abelianizations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Abelianization.html).